# How to create the union of many sets using a generator expression?

Tags: python, set, generator

Suppose I have a list of sets and I want to get the union over all sets in that list. Is there any way to do this using a generator expression? In other words, how can I create the union over all sets in that list *directly* as a `frozenset`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182801/1959808

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just use [the `.union()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.union).

```
>>> l = [set([1,2,3]), set([4,5,6]), set([1,4,9])]
>>> frozenset().union(*l)
frozenset([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9])
```

This works for any iterable of iterables.

Comment: Following vaultah's suggestion no longer works for empty lists.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that what you're trying to avoid is the intermediate creations of frozenset objects as you're building up the union?

Here's one way to do it. *NOTE:* this originally used `itertools.chain()` but, as Kenny's comment notes, the version below is slightly better:

```
import itertools

def mkunion(*args):
    return frozenset(itertools.chain.from_iterable(args))
```

Invoke like this:

```
a = set(['a','b','c'])
b = set(['a','e','f'])
c = mkunion(a,b)       # => frozenset(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'f'])
```

Comment: Use `chain.from_iterable` if you're going to `.chain(*args)`.

Comment: My performance test results (with python 3): KennyTM's response is slightly faster when number of sets < 10000, but this response is slightly faster with 30000 sets

Answer (score 4):

Nested generator expression. But I think they are a bit cryptic, so the way KennyTM suggested may be clearer.

```
frozenset(some_item for some_set in some_sets for some_item in some_set)
```

Comment: This is indeed clearer, but about 4 times slower than Kenny's solution