# Do python's variable length arguments (*args) expand a generator at function call time?

Tags: python, function, iteration, generator

Consider the following Python code:

```
def f(*args):
    for a in args:
        pass

foo = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

# Python generator expressions FTW
gen = (f for f in foo)

f(*gen)
```

Does `*args` automatically expand the generator at call-time? Put another way, am I iterating over `gen` twice within `f(*gen)`, once to expand `*args` and once to iterate over args? Or is the generator preserved in pristine condition, while iteration only happens once during the for loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The generator is expanded at the time of the function call, as you can easily check:

```
def f(*args):
    print(args)
foo = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
gen = (f for f in foo)
f(*gen)
```

will print

```
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Comment: It would be good to add to the end of the example that calling `f(*gen)` a second time returns `()`, to show that invoking `f` exhausts the generator for subsequent lines.

Answer (score 2):

Why not look and see what `gen` is in `f()`?  Add `print args` as the first line. If it's still a generator object, it'll tell you. I would expect the argument unpacking to turn it into a tuple.

Comment: Whenever you have `f(*arg)`, `arg` itself will be always be a tuple at the function

Answer (score -1):

Your don't really need

```
gen = (f for f in foo)
```

Calling

```
f(*foo)
```

will output

```
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Comment: This is just the simplest possible generator, for demonstration purposes--an "identity" generator, if you will.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all - the OP definitely intended for an analytic answer that generalised for any generator.