# Are *parameters calls lazy?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, generator-expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do python's variable length arguments (*args) expand a generator at function call time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182758/do-pythons-variable-length-arguments-args-expand-a-generator-at-function-cal)

Let's say you have a function like this:

```
def give_me_many(*elements):
   #do something...
```

And you call it like that:

```
generator_expr = (... for ... in ... )
give_me_many(*generator_expr)
```

Will the elements be called lazily or will the generator run through all the possibly millions of elements before the function can be executed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182758/do-pythons-variable-length-arguments-args-expand-a-generator-at-function-cal

Comment: @thg435 I have to agree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

no they are not:

```
>>> def noisy(n):
...   for i in range(n):
...     print i
...     yield i
... 
>>> def test(*args):
...   print "in test"
...   for arg in args:
...     print arg
... 
>>> test(*noisy(4))
0
1
2
3
in test
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 14):

Arguments are always passed to a function as a tuple and/or a dictionary, therefore anything passed in with `*args` will be converted to a tuple or `**kwargs` will be converted to a dictionary. If `kwargs` is already a dictionary then a copy is made. tuples are immutable so `args` doesn't need to be copied unless it changes (by including other positional arguments or removing some arguments to named positional ones), but it will be converted from any other sequence type to a tuple.

Comment: Sounds logical, but I still don't get the connection to the question.

Comment: @erikb85, the call to `tuple(..)` (or `dict(..)`) for the conversion force the evaluation of the whole generator.

Comment: Timeit seems to confirm that calling `f(*some_tuple)` is slightly faster than calling `f(*some_list)`. Huh.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) say that

> These arguments will be wrapped up in a tuple

which means that the generator is evaluated early.