# Python: How to pass a generator to a function?

Tags: python, numpy, generator

***Quick description***:

You can probably work out what I want to do by looking at this (broken) snippet:

```
numpy.savez('tmp.npz',range(i) for i in range(2,100))
```

I'd rather not have some work-around like:

```
numpy.save('tmp.npy',[range(i) for i in range(2,100)])
```

as this means the whole nested list must be generated and held in RAM at the same time rather than each sub-list being generated, passed, and then cleared from memory.

***Formal / Longer description***:

Assuming I have some function `f` which takes an arbitrary number of arguments, all of which are lists:

```
def f(*args,**kwargs):  #all arguments are (non nested) lists.
    ...
```

But I cannot (don't want to) change the function `f` itself; and I have a generator which produces lots of lists:

```
nested=[<generator G, producing many lists>]
```

where `<G>` could be something like `range(10) for i in range(10)`

How do I feed these lists into the function? Neither `f([<G>])` nor `f(<G>)` work.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid taking up the space for all of the lists at some point.

Comment: When you say that neither `f([<G>])` or `f(<G>)` work, what does that mean? Are you get exceptions and tracebacks or bad results?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do this, unless the function is redesigned to take a single generator argument rather than arbitrary positional `*args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
np.savez("tmp.npz", *(np.arange(i) for i in range(2, 100)))
```

Note that use of `*` to "unpack" the generator of arrays into the function's arguments. I have switched to `xrange` for the outer range, to avoid building the list, and `np.arange` for the inner range, to create arrays.

```
>>> np.savez("tmp.npz", *(np.arange(i) for i in xrange(2, 100)))
>>> np.load("tmp.npz")['arr_60']
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61])
```

Comment: When do they get unpacked?  Are the resultant arrays unpacked all at once or is the generator *consumed* one array at a time?

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182801/3001761) - *"The generator is expanded at the time of the function call"*

Comment: The OP wants to avoid creating all 98 arrays in memory at once - if using `*(generator)` as a function argument accomplishes this, it would be very useful.

Comment: @wwii it doesn't. As far as I know, the function would have to be designed to accept a generator, rather than separate (even arbitrary) arguments to support this.

Comment: Sorry, been ages since I asked this question. I'll mark this ans the answer, even though it's not perfect. The `*` syntax was unknown to me at the time. afaik it is still not possible to avoid unpacking everything without modifying `f`.

Comment: @abcdaa again, unless you pass the whole generator as a single argument, you will have to iterate over it *before* calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [numpy io source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ef4806acd0f76cae16c5ce47d0d591173e056e20/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L456), you'll find that `savez(file, *args, **kwds)` is just a wrapper that calls the function `_savez(file, args, kwds, compress)`. `_savez()` takes `args` and not `*args`, so you can pass a generator that will get consumed *in* the save function and not at call time.

I didn't test it, but something like this should work:

```
from numpy.lib.npyio import _savez

_savez('tmp.npz', (range(i) for i in range(2,100)), {}, False)
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrapping a comprehension in `()` instead of `[]` will make it a generator comprehension.

Comment: Also, use `xrange()` instead of `range` if it's Python 2.x

Comment: It can't pickle generators, either.