# How to select an optimal (cost) team of sellers from a list, given a list of items needed

Tags: python

Given a list of items needed, I need to select a team of vendors so that there is a vendor for every item (no missing items) and the total cost for everything is the lowest possible. e.g.

```
vendors = [target, kmart, bunnings, walmart]
items_needed = ['rope', 'tape', 'staples', 'cardboard', 'paper']

target = (['rope', 'tape'], 200)
kmart = (['rope', 'staples', 'paper'], 1000)
bunnings = (['cardboard'], 500) 
walmart = (['rope', 'paper', 'scissors'], 240)
```

I'm able to choose a team of vendors using a greedy approach, but I don't know how you would go about getting the optimal overall team.

Because it chooses each result based on which option provides the most items for the cheapest cost per item, and then adds it to the list.

I need it to instead choose the best overall team based on cost per item, with every item needed being supplied.

So the result should be: [target, kmart, bunnings]

Because that has every item for the cheapest cost overall.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should include examples that you've tried.

Comment: @AdamGold Added, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a better way, I'll update if I find it, but to get lists of stores that together cover at least the items needed:

```
vendor_items = [v[0] for v in vendors]

# see link below
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))


[
    list(powerset(vendors))[index]
    for index, l in enumerate(powerset(vendor_items))
    if set().union(*l) >= set(items_needed) # see link below
]

# returns list of possible stores that together cover items needed
# [((['rope', 'tape'], 200), (['rope', 'staples', 'paper'], 1000), (['cardboard'], 500)),
#  ((['rope', 'tape'], 200), (['rope', 'staples', 'paper'], 1000), (['cardboard'], 500), (['rope', 'paper', 'scissors'], 240))]
```

[How to merge sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438218/4711754)

[Powerset method from itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

`powerset` is overkill: for`powerset([1,2,3])` if `(1,2)` works we don't need `(1,2,3)`, plus you really don't want to call `list(powerset(vendor_items))` if you can help it